# A baby that you find him / her

Tags: word-request

What do you call a found baby who's parents due to poverty or some other reasons put them on a way and go a way?

I searched a lot, but I didn't find any term to use in this case. Actually I doubt if there is any specific term for this case.

I would be thankful it if someone could let me know about it.

Comment: "unwanted/abandoned"? ["baby drop-off box" for unwanted newborns](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/indiana-introduces-first-baby-drop-off-box-unwanted-newborns-knights-of-columbus-catholic-a7011536.html)

Comment: An orphan? It's usually used when the parents have died, but I think also works when they have abandoned the child.

Comment: This is probably a little left of center, but maybe a baby who has been put up for adoption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest word for what you want is probably [**foundling**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foundling):

> an infant found after its unknown parents have abandoned it

[It's a bit old-fashioned and not as popular as it used to be](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foundling&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfoundling%3B%2Cc0), but it's still extant.